# Registering a service that has a dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I'd like to have the following structure

A `Repository` has `DbContext` injecting into it.
A `Controller` has `Repository` injecting into it.

So a controller uses the repo and the repo already has context in it.

So I register the context in `startup.cs`

`services.AddDbContext<DbContext> x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:DBCS")));`

Register the repo right below the above line

`services.AddScoped(x => new DB.Tasker.LogEntryRepo());`

and then use the DIed repo inside the controller

```
private LogEntryRepo _repo;
    public LogsController(LogEntryRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
```

Problem is compiler complains quite predictably complains about this line `services.AddScoped(x => new DB.Tasker.LogEntryRepo());` as the repo obviously doesn't have a parameterless controller.
What's the proper way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does your `LogEntryRepo` currently implement an interface?

Comment: It inherits from a generics class that implements an interface. It's a pattern I used for my older noncore EF interactions and it worked well for me over the years. But for the sake of this example let's say it doesn't. I want to understand how this is supposed to be done properly the netcore and efcore way.

Comment: Here is a pretty good article in regards to implementing the repository pattern in netcore: https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register them in Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:DBCS")));
```

DI the DbContext into your Repository

```
public MyRepository(MyDbContext myDbContext)
{
   _dbContext = myDbContext;
}
```

And DI the Repository into your Controller.  Notice we are using `IMyRepository`, not `MyRepository`.  We tell it which repository to DI when we register it in `Startup.cs`.  Be sure that your repository implements your interface.

```
public MyController(IMyRepository myRepository)
{
   _repository = myRepository;
}
```

Then in your controller you can do things like

```
_repository.DoSomeDatabaseStuff(param1, param2);
```

If you don't take advantage of the Interface, then you're ignoring the power of DI.  This allows you to also do things like create a UnitTest where you mock a repository.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyMockRepository>();
```

In MyMockRepository, you may fake the data, or ensure your database connections and queries work, but simply fail to commit or automatically rollback changes.

Comment: Add explanation why we need to abstract the repository, like for the benefit of unit testing, flexiblity of implementation

Comment: @Sherlock I (quickly) mentioned the abstraction gives you the ability to create a mock repository for unit testing.  Are you asking to explain the benefits of being able to unit test using a mock repository?  I think that's getting a little beyond the scope of OP's question :)